# sregex_iterator next and end.. How does this work?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Folks, I am new to C++. So please excuse me for my ignorance here.  I am trying to understand the below code that I got online.   What does while (next != end) line exactly do? When I printed the address of &next and &end they were always different (even post while loop). I take `std::sregex_iterator next` and  `std::sregex_iterator end` are two different instances. So how come `while (next != end)` line thinks they will be equal at some point of time? I looked under the hood. It seems to be `regex_iterator<string::const_iterator>`.

I tried to understand the constructor etc but do not want to list all those I found cause those might not be related. Just to let you know I am from Java world but have been taking courses to understand C++.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
string subject("This is a test");
    try {
      std::regex re("\\S+");
      std::sregex_iterator next(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re);
      std::sregex_iterator end;
       
      while (next != end) {     
        std::smatch match = *next;
        std::cout << match.str() << "\n";
        std::cout << match.position() << "\n";
        next++;    
      }
      
    } catch (std::regex_error& e) {
      // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
```

Comment: `=` checks equality not identity. Are you perhaps coming form Java? C++ uses value-semantics. You can have two objects that compare equal, eg `int x = 3; int y = 3;` then `x==y` is `true` even though `&x != &y`

Comment: The `==` operator in C++ doesn't necessarily compare addresses. `next` and `end` are iterators (a thing that can be used to move through a collection; often implemented as a facade over a pointer).

Comment: oh yes Java ;). Don't try to apply what you know from java to C++. Despite very similar looking syntax, they almost could not be more different in how stuff actually works

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - right so at one point of time the value of both next and end will be nothing (something like null) and the while loop will terminate? Tried to print the value of next and end but it does not like it. I assume like toString in Java there is some operator or some overloading in C++ which when done  will facilitate the value to be printed?

Comment: yes there are two aspects to your question. I tried to address both in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just to let you know I am from Java world but have been taking courses to understand C++

That seems to be the reason for your confusion. C++ in contrast to Java is using value semantics. This means, when you compare two object via `==` then it does not test identity, but equality, ie the values are compared.

Consider this

```
int x = 42;
int y = 42;
```

Thats two distinct objects, but their values are the same:

```
assert( x == y );
assert( &x != &y );
```

Java has this quirk of boxed and simple types (not sure how they are actually called), but in C++ also custom types that can overload `==` are expected to use value-semantics. For example

```
std::string x{"Foo"};
std::string y{"Foo"};
assert( x == y );
assert( &x != &y );
```

Input iterators often do not know beforehand where the input ends. Same is true for `std::istream_iterator` for example. One possible way to enable `next != end` in such case is that `operator++` sets some internal state that signals that the end of input is reached. Then `next != end`, just checks whether that flag is set in `next` (which of course also requires `end`, ie a default constructed iterator to be "special", though thats implementation details, basically you just need to know that it works ;).